# How to run findAndModify with cl-mongo?

Tags: mongodb, common-lisp

I'm trying to implement a simple message queue in MongoDB. But I can't get findAndModify to work with cl-mongo.

In mongo shell I can do this (reformatted for readability):

```
> db.queue2.insert(
{
    "data": "test",
    "date_created": new Date(),
    "date_updated": null,
    "date_completed": null,
    "state": 0
})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

> db.queue2.findAndModify(
{
    query: {"state": 0},
    update: {
        $inc: {"state": 1},
        $currentDate: {"date_updated": false}
    }
})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56e7142c3ade7afa5209bf0f"),
    "data" : "test",
    "date_created" : ISODate("2016-03-14T19:42:36.860Z"),
    "date_updated" : null,
    "date_completed" : null,
    "state" : 0
}

> db.queue2.find()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56e7142c3ade7afa5209bf0f"),
    "data" : "test",
    "date_created" : ISODate("2016-03-14T19:42:36.860Z"),
    "date_updated" : ISODate("2016-03-14T19:43:10.499Z"),
    "date_completed" : null,
    "state" : 1
}
```

I can use `find` in cl-mongo:

```
> (pp (db.find "queue2" (kv "query" (kv "state" 0))))

  {
    "_id" -> objectid(56E858283ADE7AFA5209BF10)
    "data"  -> test
    "date_created"  -> CL-MONGO::BSON-TIME Tue Mar 15 2016 19:44:56 (GMT+1)
    "date_updated"  -> NIL
    "date_completed"  -> NIL
    "state"  -> 0.0d0
  }
```

I try to run `findAndModify` with `db.run-command`. Reading the documentation and cl-mongo code, I think it should be called like this:

```
> (pp (db.run-command "findAndModify"
            :arg (kv (kv "query" (kv "state" 0))
                     (kv "update" (kv "$inc" (kv "state" 1))))
            :collection "queue2"))

  {
    "ok"  -> 0.0d0
    "errmsg"  -> need remove or update
  }
NIL
```

I've tried some variantions like `:findAndModify`, trying to pass parameters in a list, etc, but I keep getting the same error.

I should probably mention that I'm new to both Lisp and MongoDB, so in case I've missed something obvious, I apologize.

**How do you run findAndModify with cl-mongo?**

Answer (score 0):

Initial thought: the `update` and `query` are both *present* in the arguments to "findAndModify", but perhaps they're "too deep", and need to be "top-level" in the key-value map passed in?